# Re-flagging an unflagged question

Tags: support, flags, retracted-close-votes

I just flagged a question for closure as too broad. I almost immediately decided 'opinion-based' was more correct so I retracted my original flag but now I apparently can't choose to re-flag for anything under 'should be closed'. Is there a delay before you can re-flag or is this an intentional permanent removal of my ability to re-flag as 'should be closed' even though I'm intending to propose closure for a different reason?

Possibly related - my 'flags remaining' now shows as '9' (not '10') - does this mean even though I retracted it, my previous flag is still active until someone reviews it?

Comment: "Possibly related": http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/913503

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's by design. Once cast, and then retracted, you're prevented from casting the same flag again. It's to prevent the mountains of grief that could result in letting people run amok with casting, retracting, and re-casting flags.

You might as well forget about it and move on. If you're feeling kind, you might mention in the comments in the question that you think it's too opinion based. If other people agree, they'll vote to close themselves.

Comment: Okay,  thanks. So does my total available flags ever go back to 10?

Comment: (It's on hold now, by the way - 'too broad', so maybe I should have stuck with my first instinct...)