# Are retracted flags still reviewed/processed by moderators?

Tags: support, flags, retracted-flags

I have flagged a post as "*in need of moderator intervention*" with detailed explanation, but then I realised that actually "*very low quality*" flag fits quite well, so I retracted my first one. 
Unfortunately I was not aware that one cannot add description to "*very low quality*" flag and I think that detailed reason of flagging is in the case of this post essential.

I wanted then to restore my previous flag, but it's not possible anymore. I get this error message:

> You have already flagged this post for moderator attention

Hence my question: 
Are retracted flags still reviewed/processed by moderators? 
 If not, then what should I do? It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Re-flagging an unflagged question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283585/re-flagging-an-unflagged-question) Short answer is, leave a comment under the post and someone else should flag it.

Comment: Retracted flags are still viewable should a moderator view the post you flagged, but moderators cannot dismiss as "helpful" when retracted, and I believe they disappear from their list of flags to review. So... reviewed/processed? No, not really. The other bits of your question are answered by Mark's proposed duplicate, I think.

Comment: @MarkKirby not really, I am asking wether it would be still reviewed.

Comment: That is fair, it is an answer to half your question "If not, then what should I do?" but I see your point, I removed the flag.

Comment: You can only have one flag active on a post at a time. If you've retracted both the original custom mod-flag and the VLQ flag, then you should be able to raise a new custom mod-flag. You won't be able to raise a VLQ flag again, as you only get to do that once. You do get to raise additional custom mod-flags, even if you've previously raised one and retracted it, or had it handled by a moderator. I've raised a custom mod-flag, retracted it, then raised another on multiple occasions on multiple SE sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just tested this, once a flag is retracted it leaves the queue but is still visible if a mod visits that specific post:

> [image]

In that case, I would leave the flag as VLQ and type your custom mod flag message in a comment saying that you couldn't custom mod flag again. If you don't flag it at all and other users don't, it is quite likely it won't be reviewed.

Comment: As long as a user doesn't have a flag active on the post, they can raise a new custom mod-flag, even if they've previously raised a custom mod-flag on that post, as long as that prior mod-flag has been resolved (i.e. retracted or handled by a mod). I've raised a new custom mod-flag on several occasions (e.g. I wanted to add additional information to the existing custom flag, so I retracted and raised a new one).

Comment: @Makyen Why does the OP say: *I wanted then to restore my previous flag, but it's not possible anymore.*

Comment: I don't know. There's not enough information provided in the question. I *suspect* they hadn't retracted their VLQ flag, as that's the most likely reason they would be unable to raise a new flag (you can only raise one at a time). Once retracted, they won't be able to re-raise a VLQ flag, as you can only raise that flag once, as is the case for all flag types, except custom mod-flags (which you can raise multiple times, but only one at a time per post).