# Change the reason of a flag to a question

Tags: support, flags, close-reasons, retracted-flags, flag-reasons

It happened that I flagged a question for a wrong reason and then I want to change my reason. So I know that I have the possibility to cancel my flag using the 'Retract Flag' button. But after canceling a flag, I have no longer the possibility to flag it again.

So how can we change the reason of the flag?

Comment: I'm assuming this was a flag to close a question? If you retract a flag, right now [you can't immediate reflag for another reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283585/369802), because it's still a close flag and you already cast one. You [could wait 14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/369802) or drop a comment on the question explaining what you think should be improved, and hope other people pick up the hint to start close-voting/flagging :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't,** at least not for closure flags. You could still flag it for another reason (spam, or for moderator attention) but those are usually not appropriate.

But does it really matter? The effect of the closure flag is to send it into the Close Votes review queue, and it will take five (on some sites, like Stack Overflow three) other users to actually close the question. Your close reason does not have a direct influence about what's shown in the banner when the question get closed (though the reviewers will be able to see your choice).

If you're really worried about it, leave a comment explaining the actual reason you want to close the question. The author may even improve it sufficiently for that comment alone.

Comment: For flags it doesn't matter much, no. For close votes themselves it would be useful to be able to change the reason, for example, after edits have been made.